# NodeJS - Async await com mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou criando uma API com nodeJS e mongoose, estou tentando criar um usuário usando async await, porém não obtive sucesso, sempre que envio os dados eles não são salvos, já chequei toda a conexão com o BD e tudo, inclusive fiz este mesmo código com promise(then/catch) e funcionou, porém com o async await, não

O que está errado, e como ficaria da forma correta?

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const Database = "mongodb://localhost:27017/ecommerce"

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);

exports.createNewUser = async (username, email, password) => {
    try {

        await mongoose.connect(Database)

        const user = User.findOne({ email: email });

        if (user) {
            mongoose.disconnect();
            throw new Error("Este e-mail já está em uso")
        }
        const nUser = new User({ username, email, password: bcrypt.hash(password, 10) });

        nUser.save();

    } catch (err) {
       console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Código (que funciona) com promessas:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const Database = "mongodb://localhost:27017/ecommerce"

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
});


const User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);

exports.createNewUser = (username, email, password) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mongoose
            .connect(Database)
            .then(() => {
                return User.findOne({ email: email });
            })
            .then(user => {
                if (user) {
                    mongoose.disconnect();
                    reject("Este e-mail já está em uso");
                } else {
                    return bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
                }
            })
            .then(hashedPassword => {
                let user = new User({
                    username: username,
                    email: email,
                    password: hashedPassword
                });
                return user.save();
            })
            .then(() => {
                mongoose.disconnect();
                resolve();
            })
            .catch(err => {
                mongoose.disconnect();
                reject(err);
            });
    });
};
```

Comment: Voce colocou `await User.findOne({ email: email });` e `await nUser.save();` e mesmo assim nao funcionou? Foi isso?

Comment: Podes mostrar o código com Promise que funcionou?

Comment: Sergio, ai está o código com promises. E Sim, Cardel, tentei também o que vc comentou e também não funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você simplesmente não está utilizando o `await` nos métodos que retornam uma interface *Promise-like*. Procure saber mais sobre o [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) para saber de fato quando utilizá-lo. Em resumo, utilize-o em métodos que retornam uma promessa.

Desse modo, faltou usar o `await` nos métodos `findOne`, `disconnect`, `bcrypt.hash` e `save`.

Assim:

```js
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Database = "mongodb://localhost:27017/ecommerce";

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);

exports.createNewUser = async (username, email, password) => {
    await mongoose.connect(Database);

    const user = await User.findOne({ email: email }); // Faltou `await` aqui.

    if (user) {
        await mongoose.disconnect(); // Faltou `await` aqui.
        throw new Error("Este e-mail já está em uso");
    }
    const nUser = new User({
        username,
        email,
        password: await bcrypt.hash(password, 10) // Faltou `await` aqui.
    });

    await nUser.save(); // Faltou `await` aqui.
};
```

Coloquei comentário nos lugares em que o `await` era necessário.

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado mais uma vez, Luiz! =')